# Why parent scope in direcrtive not change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directive.
When I change data in parent scope from the child scope, the data no changes.
You can test by click on one of the li elements.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7ewMokT2vTnLWBFEdm14?p=preview

HTML

```
    <ez-select>
 <ez-option title="option 1">
        Option 1 inside
        <input ng-model="x">{{x}}
    </ez-option>
  <ez-option title="option 2">
        Option 2 inside
    </ez-option>
</ez-select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
m.directive('ezSelect',function(){
    return {
      template:'<ul ng-transclude></ul><br>Selected: {{selected}}',
      transclude:true,
      link:function($scope){
        $scope.selected=1
      }
    }
  });
    m.directive('ezOption',function(){
        return {
            template:'<li></li><div ng-show=selected ng-transclude class=body></div>',
            link:function ($scope,iElement,iAttrs,controller,tanscludeFn){
                iElement.find('li').html(iAttrs.title)
                iElement.closest('ez-select').find('.body')
                iElement.find('li').on('click',function(){
                  $scope.selected=false
                  $scope.$parent.selected=2
                })
            },
            controller:function($scope){
              $scope.selected=false
            },
            transclude:true
        }
    })
```

Comment: note: ALWAYS have a dot (or`[]`) in `ng-model`. You are using primitives and they don't have inheritnce like an object does so you will lose 2 way binding in child scopes. Otherwise this is the same problem as your last question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/lRKhAHB9zmHKKrcdD6nO?p=preview.

Two modifications are needed.

First, as charlietfl commented, always use an object to share model. For a detailed explanation, check this excellent article: [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). In your example, I changed `selected` to be `data.selected`.

Second, since the `onClick` event is out of Angular lifecycle, you need to use [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to trigger a `$digest` cycle manually. So:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.selected=false;
    $scope.$parent.data.selected=2;
});
```

---

Some problems regarding your coding style:

- In convention, we use `scope` instead of `$scope` in link function
- Instead of `element.on`, use `ng-click`